# OpenSSL Security Alert Mail from Google Play for Android Apps created with Flash

Tags: android, flash, air, openssl, google-play

Today, I have received a mail from Google Play that says:
"One or more of your apps is running an outdated version of OpenSSL, which has multiple security vulnerabilities. You should update OpenSSL as soon as possible. ..."

It seems that many other Android developers have received the same mail. But I've not found a helpful answer anywhere.

My question is about Air-Apps created with Flash.
I have no idea how to update OpenSSL in Flash. The only updates I receive are the automatic Creative Cloud updates from Adobe.
The latest Air version I can choose is AIR 3.8.0.1430.

Does anyone know what to do in this matter?

Another thought/hope:

My apps don't use any logins and do not exchange data with servers. They are simple gaming and information apps, even without ads, only with some links to websites.

Maybe this is a standard mail and only affects apps interacting with a server, so maybe I can relax and do nothing. Can I?

Comment: What do you mean with "latest version that I can chose is 3.8.0.1430"? That you have problems installing an up to date version? Or is your application using something that won't work with later versions? AFAIK you need to update Air to the latest version to get a secure OpenSSL version.

Comment: So the solution seems to be: Installing the latest AIR manually and rendering the apps with the new version. Thank you.